# Class.forName() within projects in an ear

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

lets say there is an EAR `ApplicationEAR` and there are two projects inside `Project1` and `Project2`.
The situation is ...

1. `Project1` has dependencies on `Project2`.
2. `Project2` calls a class in `Project1` using Class.forName()

The Problem that I am facing now is, It shows ClassNotFoundException at run-time called from `Project2`.

I can guarantee you that the class in Project1 exists and the syntax/spelling is perfectly right.

Any reason/Solution will greatly help.

Do I have to add `Project1` into dependecies of `Project2`? That will lead to circular dependency problems.

**EDIT:** both `Project1` and `Project2` are JAR Projects and there is `Project3` which is a WAR Project

Comment: Have you tried Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(...)? Anyway this is really bad design, I would recommend to move common resources to third project and make p1, p2 depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a circular dependency..

The solution is most often to send a classloader into project2, which it uses to retrieve the class from..

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29

Comment: @Neils This `Class.forName(ClassNameInProject1).newInstance();` is what I have used in `Project2`. It is after that, ClassNotFoundException occurs

Comment: Then use Class.forName(ClassNameInProject1, AnotherClassInProject1.class.getClassLoader())

Comment: I am not understanding what you did there, how do i get access to `AnotherClassInProject1`?

Comment: Either pass the originating classloader from 1 into 2, so you have it for dynamic lookups, or use the Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(className) if calls originate from project1. Was trying to find a helpful blog, but couldn't find a meaningful one.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "two projects inside"?

If your application server uses strict classloading each WAR has its own classloader. So if each "project" is a WAR they cannot see the classes of the other WAR.

You would have to move the relevant code into a jar in the lib folder of the EAR.